# Run Linux system in bootable USB but very slow on Mac laptop

Tags: mac, usb, unix, spotlight, bootable-disk

I install the Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) in the USB 3.0 drive by my MacBook Pro (Retina Early 2015 13"), but when I open Linux, everything is slow. For example, when I open Firefox, I need to wait 5 mins. I follow the answer to [USB drive very slow on Mac, works fine on Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353164/usb-drive-very-slow-on-mac-works-fine-on-windows) to try to turn off the Spotlight.

In the article, I need to click "+" to add my USB drive. However, since my USB is a bootable Linux system, the name of the drive doesn't appear. When I insert the USB, a window pops up for three options:  *eject, ignore, initialize*. Even though I select "ignore," it doesn't appear on the list that the Spotlight can opt-out of the USB.

Does anyone know how to opt-out of the bootable USB for the spotlight? Any way we can increase the read speed for bootable Linux USB on a Mac?

Update 1/19: My Mac system
[image: My Mac running Ubuntu]

Update 1/20:
So, I followed the article to go to the MacOS system to add the out-opt list for the USB flash drive. The situation happened to like the above-mentioned three options. I agree probably is not the spotlight issue, but the article mentions a Linux system installed in USB, and turning off the spotlight to solve the issue...

I installed the Linux system into the USB 3.0 flash drive 64  GB (blue color port), and I check the USB port on my laptop. It has two 3.0 ports for sure. The start-up process for my laptop is that I press the power > select which store like USB storage (Linux system) or SSD storage (MacOS system) > Login my password. But, when I select USB storage to use Linux. The start-up takes 5 to 10 mins before showing the Linux desktop.

The other big problem is that when I install packages like "sudo apt-get install xxxx" or "sudo apt-get upgrade". The progress runs very slowly. Even though I have changed the source of the update server by Software & Updates > Download from > Select the best server. Still, it is slow....

Comment: Which **SPECIFIC** Mac do you have? Add the model to your question. Depending on the age of the Mac the USB port might just be really slow, EG USB-2 or some such.

Comment: @SteveChambers Hi, my mac is Pro 12, I bought at 2016. I just attached the info. pic.

Comment: If you are booted directly to Ubuntu, then Spotlight is a red herring, as it's not running. What type of drive are you running from, HD, SSD, 'memory stick' of some sort?

Comment: If your USB stick contains an Ubuntu live system (the one you boot from when running Linux), it can't be mounted on macOS so you get the eject/ignore/initialize error. But as Tetsujin already said: This is not a Spotlight issue.

Comment: There's not a lot clear here.  USB driver?  To what driver are you referring?  Also, you mentioned a USB 3.0 *driver* but you never indicated if the USB port *and* the USB drive were both USB 3.  For all we know you could have a USB 2.0 flash and that's the reason for the poor performance.  Please supply additional details.

Comment: @Allan I assume "USB drive".

Comment: That makes  more sense @nohillside.  Since “driver” was used three times I assumed it wasn’t a typo.

Comment: Thanks so much for your follow. I just updated more information.

Comment: When installing Ubuntu, did you use persistent mode? This is where the normal operating system reads/writes are done in RAM instead of the system drive (the flash drive) and this RAM is written to the system drive on shutdown, then read on startup. Or, is that something that is no longer used?

Comment: Might it help if we migrate this to Unix&Linux?

Comment: It probably just comes down to trying to run an OS off a flash drive. They're just too slow. This was one of the reasons Windows abandoned WinToGo. To achieve full USB3 speeds, you need an SSD, or at a push, a fast HD.